# Unable to find JSONReader for parameterised-typed custom class in test, despite import

Tags: scala, spray, scalatest, spray-json

I have a custom class as follows

```
object SafeList {
  def apply[A](x: List[A]): SafeList[A] = if (x == null) EmptyList else HasItems[A](x)
}

sealed abstract class SafeList[+A] extends Product with Serializable {
  def get: List[A]
}

final case class HasItems[+A](x: List[A]) extends SafeList[A] {
  def get = x
}

case object EmptyList extends SafeList[Nothing] {
  def get = Nil
}
```

And a formatter for the SafeList which looks like this

```
...
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

trait SafeCollectionFormats {
  implicit def safeListFormat[A: RootJsonFormat] = new RootJsonFormat[SafeList[A]] {

    def read(json: JsValue): SafeList[A] = {
      val list: List[A] = listFormat[A].read(json)
      SafeList[A](list)
    }

    def write(sl: SafeList[A]): JsValue =
      listFormat[A].write(sl.get)
  }
}
object SafeCollectionFormats extends SafeCollectionFormats
```

And that compiles.

But when I add a test for my formatter, like so....

```
...
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
import marshalling.SafeCollectionFormats._
...

  "Unmarshalling a json array with items" should "produce a SafeList with items" in {
    val json: JsValue = JsArray(JsString("a"), JsString("b"), JsString("c"))
    val list = List("a", "b", "c")

    val result = json.convertTo[SafeList[String]]

    assertResult(list)(result)
  }

...
```

I get the following compilation error

```
Error:(14, 32) Cannot find JsonReader or JsonFormat type class for myapp.types.SafeList[String]
    val result = json.convertTo[SafeList[String]]
                               ^
```

I *think* there may be something in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/spray-user/Cannot$20find$20JsonReader$20or$20JsonFormat$20type$20class/spray-user/FJ4Mi2pzTtM/3l2oSHo-I4wJ) answer to help me but it's a bit advanced for me.  I thought my implicit safeListFormat *was* the JsonReader for my SafeList and i'm importing it into my Spec.  I dont know if the parameterised types are confusing things?

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**   Whilst my test at the moment is creating a SafeList of Strings, the ultimate intention is to create a SafeList of my domain objects.  I will need to add a second test that builds a JsArray of MyObjects.  And so the type of A - in JSON terms will be different.  My SafeList needs to cope with both simple objects like Strings, and domain objects.  I think I might raise this as a second SO question but I mention it here for context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me with just one little change: I made `SafeCollectionFormats` extend `DefaultJsonProtocol`.

I also had to change the context bound for your `safeListFormat` to `[A: JsonFormat]`.

```
trait SafeCollectionFormats extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit def safeListFormat[A: JsonFormat] = new RootJsonFormat[SafeList[A]] {

    def read(json: JsValue): SafeList[A] = {
      val list: List[A] = listFormat[A].read(json)
      SafeList[A](list)
    }

    def write(sl: SafeList[A]): JsValue =
      listFormat[A].write(sl.get)
  }
}

object SafeCollectionFormats extends SafeCollectionFormats
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That's a great help, thank you!  But would you be able to explain why?  
I was basing my approach on spray-jsons formatters eg. https://github.com/spray/spray-json/tree/master/src/main/scala/spray/json, and other examples on the internet that have their implicits in traits with companion objets that extend those traits.  Do you know what prevents that working in my case?   Without understanding that I'll probably make the same mistakes in future :(

Comment: A followup:  Whilst my test at the moment is creating a SafeList of Strings, the ultimate intention is to create a SafeList of my domain objects.  I just tried adding a test that builds a JsArray of MyObjects, and adding a second implicit format that extends RootJsonFormat.  But now the compiler can't find the JsonReader for the SafeList[String] again. I expect because the two implicit methods both create new RootJsonFormat[SafeList[A]], but the type of A is intended to be different depending on the complexity of the object in the SafeList

Comment: I edited my answer. It also works with `trait` + `companion object`

Comment: So it seems like it is necessary for DefaultJsonProtocol, rather than use `import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._`.   I'd love to understand why that is that case - i'm still trying to get my head around implicit scope, - but i'll ask that on the spray form separately.  Thank you so much mfirry - you've unblocked me :)